# Powershell Click Through Transparent

Tags: forms, powershell

I need to make a window click through-able when transparent.

```
$form.Transparencykey = "Red"
$form.BackColour = "Red"
```

This allows me to see through the form, but not click objects through the transparent window.
I can't find any examples anywhere of ways to do this in PowerShell. Is there a way to make the window transparent but not allow clicks to be transferred to the windows below?

Comment: That's how `Transparencykey` works. From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx): Any mouse actions, such as the click of the mouse, that are performed on the transparent areas of the form will be transferred to the windows below the transparent area. For example, if the client region of a form is made transparent, clicking the mouse on that area would send the event notification of the click to any window that is below it.

Comment: It will allow me to select controls under a transparent Panel control . but not under the form its self. hmmm think i need a screenshot.

Comment: http://imgur.com/JLXGeiu
I can't click "Sample Music" through the transparent form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the problem and its the colour I selected was a system colour.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/199a4ca5-38c2-4ade-aad4-31d1a30a1334/interesting-some-color-as-transparentkey-makes-form-not-clickthrough?forum=winforms

this article explains. so now I have modified the colour to "Silver" I can click through. If you set to say "Red" you can't.